# Why is Coulombs formula different in the solution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

I've been trying to solve this but I'm stuck. I thought the formula for Coulomb's law was $$F = (k* q1*q1)/r^2.$$
In the solution, first the charge is divided by the distance and then the whole thing is squared.
Is coulomb's law different for equal charges or is the solution wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take into account that $q_1=q_2$, which is true in this case because all protons have the same charge, then $q_1*q_2=q_1^2$, that's why the formula $F=k*\frac{q_1*q_2}{r^2}$ can be simplified to $F=k*(\frac{q}{r})^2$, being $q\equiv q_1=q_2$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks so much!